# cant find member of RouterConfig in typescript project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have created ts project and trying to implement routing configuration, here is the error message in my route.ts file.

> [ts] Module
>   '"d:/GitHub/betAngular2/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no
>   exported member 'RouterConfig'.

I have npm 6.9.1 installed and,

> tsc -v 
>   Version 2.1.4

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';

import {LoginComponent} from './account/login.component';
import {AuthManager} from './services/authmanager';

export const appRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'login'},
    {path: 'login', component:LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthManager]}
];

export const AppRouterProvider = provideRouter(appRoutes);
```

even I have latest version why this code piece for works(I searched no problems looks in origin) others but not mine ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! We can't help you if we can't see your code. If you do not want to disclose your code, just show us the part that is giving errors. Otherwise, we can't help.

Comment: I shared it but while editing in code scope there were a syntax error I dont think why it is not displaying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RouterConfig` has been removed. Please use `Routes` instead.

```
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'login'},
    {path: 'login', component:LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthManager]}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        (...)
    ],
    (...)
})
```